# How to fix UITextField position of in Apportable

Tags: keyboard, apportable

I am trying Apportable starter kit.

Currently `UITextField` scrolls up automatically when I touch it to input some text if the text field was under the keyboard. And also any other views scrolls up together.

I tried several view hierarchy configurations to fix it at specific position, but whole the view hierarchies always scrolls up.

How to fix views at specific position regardless of existence of keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually caused an inconsistency of some handset manufacturers versions of Android; stock Android does not do this. We usually suggest for developers to attempt to account for this by placing edit fields in locations that this will not be an issue.

What device are you seeing this happen on?

Comment: I don't remember now exactly but I think it was `SHW-M250L` which is Samsung Galaxy S2. Or some other Galaxy S1 variants. I will check and reply later.